# Best way to send grouped data into arima/lm and rebuild original columns in R?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I have the below data that I want to send into an arima model to forecast missing tickets_listed and then forecast price with a linear model.  Problem is the data has multiple categories with some data missing in each category.

I want to know if there's a better way to rollup the dataset before I send into the models so I can rebuild the dataset afterwards.  Current method has cross-sections of id + taxonomy, but when it's sent through the arima model it's still rolled up.  Need to split it back or find better method.

Code(data looks like this not exact):

```
df <- data.frame(

id <- rep(seq(2694065, length=62, by = 1),10),
list_date <- rep(seq(as.Date("2017-06-01"), length=62, by = 1),10),
event <- sample(c("Baseball","Minors","Music","NA"), 620, replace =   
TRUE),
event_date <- rep(seq(as.Date("2017-09-01"), length=62, by = 1),10),
ticket_ct <- sample(10:11000, size=620, replace = TRUE),
price <- sample(10:600, size=620, replace = TRUE),
cat1 <- sample(c("Sox", "Twins", "Phil", "Band1", "Band2"),620,replace 
= TRUE),
cat2 <- sample(c("Mets", "Hops", "NA", "Phil"),620, replace = TRUE),
venue <- sample(c("Stadium","BallPark", "Concert Hall"),620, replace =   
TRUE)
)

#Create a list that contains the time series info for each
#combination of id + taxonomy
list1 <- dlply(df, .(id, taxonomy))

#Turn list1 into an XTS object so we can use it for time-series   
#analysis
xtsobject <- llply(list1, function(list) {
xts(x=list[,c("id","ticket_ct","price")],   
order.by=list[,"listing_date"])
})

#Create function to pass to lapply
arimafunc <- function(list) {
fity <- auto.arima(list$ticket_ct)
forecast <- forecast(fity,h=31)
return(forecast)
}

#Run the arimafunc
forecasts <- lapply(xtsobject,arimafunc)
```

Comment: if anyone is looking for a similar method, I was able to solve my dilemma with this articles:  https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/sweep/vignettes/SW01_Forecasting_Time_Series_Groups.html

Comment: Feel free to post an answer to your own question, so others can refer to what worked for you

Comment: that's exactly what I did except in a comment @camille no need to write up a response as the link explains quite well

Comment: No sarcasm. I'm saying that if you came up with a good solution, you can write up an answer to your own question and show how you made use of what you learned from the vignette. Then it becomes reference for other people who have a similar question later. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) about self-answers.

Comment: @camille I see your point, I'll write something up when I have time